# Image View change image after paticular time interval

Tags: android, android-imageview

I using Image View and I want to change an image at particular interval.

I have 10 images.

How i do this?

Comment: Have you tried something? This is not a "do it for me" site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need TimerTask for it.

Below Snippet will help you

It will change image every 3 seconds.

```
  timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {

                            if (flag > 1) {
                                timer.cancel();
                                timer = null;
                            } else
                                imageView.setImageResource(images[flag++]);

                        }
                    });

                }
            }, System.currentTimeMillis(), 3000);
```